# Warning MSB4056: The MSBuild engine must be called on a single-threaded-apartment

Tags: c#, msbuild

I am getting this error while trying to build my ASP.Net solution using a C# console application:

> MSBUILD : warning MSB4056: The MSBuild engine must be called on a
>   single-threaded-apartment. Current threading model is "MTA".
>   Proceeding, but some tasks may not function correctly.

This is my code:

```
Engine engine = new Engine();
engine.BinPath = @"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319";

FileLogger logger = new FileLogger();
logger.Parameters = @"logfile=C:\temp\build.log";
engine.RegisterLogger(logger);

bool success = engine.BuildProjectFile(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ProjectPath"]);

engine.UnregisterAllLoggers();
if (success)
    Console.WriteLine("Build succeeded.");
else
    Console.WriteLine(@"Build failed. View C:\temp\build.log for details");
```

Comment: Posted it as an answer. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Just decorate the main method with `[STAThread]`.

That said, the only issues that could cause if you can tasks that calls into COM methods. In other words, it is generally safe to ignore it.